# Show that the complex of $A$-modules splits

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Let $(C_{*},d_{*})$ be a complex of $A$-modules. We say that the complex splits if there exist a family of morphisms $s_n:C_n \to C_{n+1}$ such that $d=dsd$.
>
> Show that every acyclic complex of free $A$-modules which is bounded from below splits.

EDIT:

So by reading another posts, I came to a possible solution however im not sure if it is correct:

I was able to prove that for every $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $\ker(d_n)$ is a direct summand of the free module $C_n$ and therfore projective. I could therfore find a $s_n : \ker(d_n) \subseteq C_n \to C_{n+1}$ such that $d=dsd$. However my $s_n$ is defined in $\ker(d_n)$ and not in the entire module, and since $\ker(d_n)$ need not to be linearly independant, it doesn't necessairily extend linearly to $C_n$. It is enough to define it in $\ker(d_n)$?

---

So I consider my complex

$$\cdots\to C_{n+1}\xrightarrow{d_{n+1}}C_n \xrightarrow{d_n} C_{n-1} \to\cdots \to C_1 \xrightarrow{d_1} C_0 \to 0 \to 0 \to\cdots$$

So I start by defining $s_0$. Since the complex is acyclic, $d_1$ is an epimorphism and then $Im(d_1)=C_0$. Since $C_0$ is free let $\{y_i\}_{i \in I}$ be its basis, then for every $y_i \in C_0$, there exist $x \in C_1$ such that $d_1(x)=y_i$. Define $s_0:C_0 \to C_{1}$ by $s_0(y_i)=x$. In this way, $s_0$ is well defined and given $z \in C_1$, $d_1(z)=\sum a_i y_i $ while

$$d_1s_0d_1(z)=d_1s_0(\sum a_i y_i)=\sum a_i d_1 s_0 (y_i)=\sum a_i y_i =d_1 (z)$$

However, when I try to extend this for the module $C_n$ I find my self with the problem that $d_{n}$ is not an epimorphism any more, but we only have the exactitude of the sequence in the place $n$, that is, $\ker(d_n)=Im(d_{n+1})$ and it would be nice to define $s_{n-1}$ in a similar manner, that is, by defining it conveniently in $Im(d_{n+1})$ but since $Im(d_{n+1}) \subset C_n$ is not necessarily linearly independent, i can't be sure $s_{n-1}$ extends linearly.

Am I on the correct track? Any suggestion?

Comment: Should not this come from the fact that any short exact sequence ending with projective module(free module here) splits?

Comment: I don't understand you edit, specially the part "since $\ker(d_n)$ need not to be linearly independent". You just proved that $\ker(d_n)$ was a direct summand, say $C_n=\ker(d_n)\oplus A_n$. You can extend $s_n$ by requiring it to be 0 on $A_n$.

Comment: How can I be sure that the extension is linear? I had thought of extending it to 0 on $A_n$, but I took $x \in \ker(d_n)$, $y \notin \ker(d_n)$ and then, since $\ker(d_n)$ is submodule, $x+y \notin \ker(d_n)$ and therefore $s_n (x+y)=0 \neq s_n(x) + 0 = s_n(x) + s_n (y)$

Answer (score 0):

as the above comment said.it is not difficult.

- first,since $C_0$ is projective,there exists $s_1$ such that $d_1s_1=Id_{C_0}$.
- second,take a natural decomposition $C_2 \rightarrow ^{\beta_1}K_1 \rightarrow^{i_1}C_1$ such that $\beta_1$ is epic. and $i_1$ is monic.

So $i_1$ is split monomorphism,there exists $p_1$ such that $p_1i_1=Id_{K_1}$.In particular,K_1 is projective,so there exists $\alpha_1$ such that $\beta_1\alpha_1=Id_{K_1}$.

Take $s_2=\alpha_1p_1$,so $d_2s_2d_2=i_1\beta_1\alpha_1p_1i_1\beta_1=i_1\beta_1=d_2$.

By the same way,you can get the result.